# Quartz.Net JobStore using RavenDb

Tags: c#, ravendb, quartz.net

I'm working on a large scale project, and I'm allowing users to schedule operations.

I've been using the Quartz.net library, which worked fine, using the (default) RAMStore. However, as I make progress, I need to use a more persistent storage for the scheduled jobs.

Since I'm already using RavenDb all over the project, I was hoping to use it as the IJobStore implementation for Quartz.net. However, implementing that turned out to be much more complex than expected:

- The various Key are not easily serializable for RavenDb to save/load them
- The IJobStore implementation is expected to do much more than just CRUD operations over jobs and triggers - it appears to contain some "real" business logic

I've also tried "interning" the Quartz.net code into my project, but that brought-up a large number of other issues, and seems counter-productive to me.

Does anyone have a solution/implementation for the IJobStore using RavenDb?

Comment: https://github.com/iftahbe/quartznet-RavenDB